# Some doubts regarding "unset" feature in unix

Tags: unix

Firstly, I have defined a variable `count=10` and made it readonly. Now, how can I unset it?

Secondly, on unsetting a variable it sets it to `NULL` string. I have set `dir=/home/kundan`
Now on unsetting dir, if I do `echo $dir`, output is null, but if I give `cd $dir` it goes to `/home/kundan`.

Why is this happening?

I expected that after unsetting `dir` it should not go to `/home/kundan`

Comment: Can you pls post the code you are trying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset is working as expected as it sets the @dir to null. It wont work if the variable is a readonly variable.

on cd $dir , if the $dir is empty or if it doesn't exist . It will go to the default directory. i.e. /home/username.

Just try cd $abcd(where $abcd is not defined) from a different path , since $abcd is not defined , it will end up in /home/username

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it is readonly, you can not really unset it.If you want that, you should not make it readonly.See the [man page](http://man.cx/unset).